# Kafka-exporter deployment with custom configmap

Tags: deployment, devops, kubernetes-helm, configmap, kafka-exporter

I want to deploy Kafka-exporter using helm with custom configmap, my values.yaml file looks like this:

```
# kafkaServer:
#   - kafka0.svc.cluster.local:9092
#   - kafka1.svc.cluster.local:9092
#   - kafka2.svc.cluster.local:9092

service: 
  annotations:
    prometheus.io/path: /metrics
    prometheus.io/scrape: "true"

prometheus:
  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: true
    namespace: observability
    additionalLabels:
      release: prometheus
```

deployment.yaml chart looks like this:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "prometheus-kafka-exporter.fullname" . }}
  labels:
    app: {{ template "prometheus-kafka-exporter.name" . }}
    chart: {{ template "prometheus-kafka-exporter.chart" . }}
    release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.replicaCount }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "prometheus-kafka-exporter.name" . }}
      release: {{ .Release.Name }}
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
{{ toYaml .Values.annotations | indent 8 }}
      labels:
        app: {{ template "prometheus-kafka-exporter.name" . }}
        release: {{ .Release.Name }}
    spec:
      {{- if .Values.securityContext }}
      securityContext:
      {{- toYaml .Values.securityContext | nindent 8 }}
      {{- end }}
      serviceAccountName: {{ template "prometheus-kafka-exporter.serviceAccountName" . }}
      containers:
        - args:
            - '--verbosity={{ .Values.verbosity }}'
          {{- if .Values.sarama.logEnabled }}
            - '--log.enable-sarama'
          {{- end }}
           {{- range $server := .Values.kafkaServer }}
            - '--kafka.server={{ $server }}'
          {{- end }}
          {{- if .Values.kafkaBrokerVersion }}
            - '--kafka.version={{ .Values.kafkaBrokerVersion }}'
          {{- end }}
          {{- if .Values.tls.enabled }}
            - '--tls.enabled'
          {{- if .Values.tls.mountPath }}
            - '--tls.ca-file={{ .Values.tls.mountPath }}/ca.crt'
            - '--tls.cert-file={{ .Values.tls.mountPath }}/tls.crt'
            - '--tls.key-file={{ .Values.tls.mountPath }}/tls.key'
          {{- end }}
          {{- if .Values.tls.insecureSkipVerify }}
            - '--tls.insecure-skip-tls-verify'
          {{- else if .Values.tls.serverName }}
            - '--tls.server-name={{ .Values.tls.serverName }}'
          {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
          {{- if .Values.sasl.enabled }}
            - '--sasl.enabled'
          {{- if not .Values.sasl.handshake }}
            - '--sasl.handshake=false'
          {{- end }}
          {{- if .Values.sasl.scram.enabled }}
            - '--sasl.username=$(SCRAM_USERNAME)'
            - '--sasl.password=$(SCRAM_PASSWORD)'
            - '--sasl.mechanism={{ .Values.sasl.scram.mechanism }}'
          {{- end }}
          {{- if .Values.sasl.kerberos.enabled }}
            - '--sasl.service-name={{ .Values.sasl.kerberos.serviceName }}'
            - '--sasl.kerberos-config-path={{ .Values.sasl.kerberos.mountPath }}/kerberos.conf'
            - '--sasl.realm={{ .Values.sasl.kerberos.realm }}'
            - '--sasl.keytab-path={{ .Values.sasl.kerberos.mountPath }}/kerberos.keytab'
            - '--sasl.kerberos-auth-type={{ .Values.sasl.kerberos.kerberosAuthType }}'
          {{- end }}
          {{- if .Values.server.tls.enabled }}
            - '--server.tls.ca-file={{ .Values.server.tls.mountPath }}/ca.crt'
            - '--server.tls.cert-file={{ .Values.server.tls.mountPath }}/tls.crt'
            - '--server.tls.key-file={{ .Values.server.tls.mountPath }}/tls.key'
            - '--server.tls.mutual-auth-enabled={{ .Values.server.tls.mutualAuthEnabled }}'
          {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
          {{- if .Values.extraArgs }}
          {{- range .Values.extraArgs  }}
            - {{ . }}
          {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
          env:
          {{- range $env := .Values.env }}
            - name: {{ $env.name }}
              value: {{ $env.value }}
          {{- end }}
          {{- if .Values.sasl.scram.enabled }}
            - name: SCRAM_USERNAME
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ template "prometheus-kafka-exporter.saslScramSecretName" . }}
                  key: username
            - name: SCRAM_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: {{ template "prometheus-kafka-exporter.saslScramSecretName" . }}
                  key: password
          {{- end }}
          name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
          image: "{{ .Values.image.repository }}:{{ .Values.image.tag | default .Chart.AppVersion }}"
          imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.image.pullPolicy }}
          ports:
            - name: exporter-port
              containerPort: 9308
              protocol: TCP
{{- if .Values.liveness.enabled }}
          livenessProbe:
{{- toYaml .Values.liveness.probe | trim | nindent 12 }}
{{- end }}
{{- if .Values.readiness.enabled }}
          readinessProbe:
{{- toYaml .Values.readiness.probe | trim | nindent 12 }}
{{- end }}
          resources:
{{ toYaml .Values.resources | indent 12 }}
          {{- with .Values.containerSecurityContext }}
          securityContext:
            {{- toYaml . | nindent 12 }}
          {{- end }}
          {{- if or (.Values.tls.mountPath) (.Values.sasl.kerberos.mountPath) }}
          volumeMounts:
            {{- if .Values.tls.mountPath }}
            - mountPath: {{ .Values.tls.mountPath }}
              name: kafka-certs
              readOnly: true
            {{- end }}
            {{- if .Values.sasl.kerberos.mountPath }}
            - mountPath: {{ .Values.sasl.kerberos.mountPath }}
              name: kerberos
              readOnly: true
            {{- end }}
            {{- if .Values.server.tls.mountPath }}
            - mountPath: {{ .Values.server.tls.mountPath }}
              name: server-certs
              readOnly: true
            {{- end }}
          {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.nodeSelector }}
      nodeSelector:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.affinity }}
      affinity:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- with .Values.tolerations }}
      tolerations:
{{ toYaml . | indent 8 }}
    {{- end }}
      {{- if or (.Values.tls.mountPath) (.Values.sasl.kerberos.mountPath) }}
      volumes:
        {{- if .Values.tls.mountPath }}
        - name: kafka-certs
          secret:
            secretName: {{ .Values.tls.secretName }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- if .Values.sasl.kerberos.mountPath }}
        - name: kerberos
          secret:
            secretName: {{ .Values.sasl.kerberos.secretName }}
        {{- end }}
        {{- if .Values.server.tls.mountPath }}
        - name: server-certs
          secret:
            secretName: {{ .Values.server.tls.secretName }}
        {{- end }}
      {{- end }}
```

and i would like to use config map like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka0.svc.cluster.local:9092
  KAFKA_CLUSTERS_0_NAME: kafka0
  KAFKA_CLUSTERS_1_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka1.svc.cluster.local:9092
  KAFKA_CLUSTERS_1_NAME: kafka1
  KAFKA_CLUSTERS_2_BOOTSTRAPSERVERS: kafka2.svc.cluster.local:9092
  KAFKA_CLUSTERS_2_NAME: kafka2
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  
  name: kafka-configmap
  namespace: default
```

configmap will have in the future more and more KafkaServers, so I want to do more dynamically.
How can I update deployment.yaml file with custom configmap?

Kafka-exporter helm chart:
[Kafka-exporter helm chart](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/prometheus-kafka-exporter)

Thanks for any advice.

I tried update deployment.yaml file with configMapKeyRef, but it only takes one value each time

Comment: Where exactly did you try to add the `configMapKeyRef ` in the deployment.yaml?

Comment: under containers: part -args and -env,  i have no idea if i did it right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your end goal is to be able to add more than 1 `Kafka` server, then I guess you can just add it to the `values.yaml` file directly [here](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/blob/prometheus-kafka-exporter-1.8.0/charts/prometheus-kafka-exporter/values.yaml#L9).

So, your `values` file would end up something like this:

```
...

kafkaServer:
  - kafka-server:9092
  - kafka0.svc.cluster.local:9092
  - kafka1.svc.cluster.local:9092

...
```

If you want to configure all the `key-value` pairs in your `ConfigMap` as container environment variables, you will need to modify the configuration in the `deployment` file under `container spec`, and add something like this:

```
envFrom:
- configMapRef:
    name: kafka-configmap
```

Read more [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-configmap/#configure-all-key-value-pairs-in-a-configmap-as-container-environment-variables)

In the helm chart, you wouldn't probably wanna hardcode the `ConfigMap` name. So, change accordingly. Looking at other template files, this should work (and maintain consistency):

```
name: {{ template "prometheus-kafka-exporter.fullname" . }}
```

I haven't used this chart myself, but I think it should help you to get the desired result (with minor tweaks based on your setup).

Hope it helps.